# Can I use BRISQUE to compare different filtering techniques for the same acquired image?

Tags: filtering

BRISQUE compares your image with a pre-learned model with opinion scores. I am not sure about this but would image resolution affect the result of BRISQUE?

Moreover, if I have 2 filters and I would like to compare the results of using either filter to get the better result, can I use BRISQUE to quantify the better filter?

Additionally, if I have a 2-step filter, should I compare the result from each step with the previous image by using PSNR; that is step 1 against original and step 2 against step 1? or should I just apply the final result into BRISQUE?

Thanks to who can help me understand this better!

Comment: Welcome here! Could provide a link or more details about BRISQUE (first mention for me)

Comment: I can link the journal paper [link](https://live.ece.utexas.edu/publications/2012/TIP%20BRISQUE.pdf) or MATLAB's function page [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/brisque.html?s_tid=srchtitle) I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It would be better to update the original post, with full titles, DOI